# angular js: value set to 0 for all scopes, when no data found

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have default/ hard coded select option(4 options) and json data.
And since the data is missing of "SWIZ" in my json obj. that gives weird output when i click on it. You can see the fiddle...https://jsfiddle.net/tffv2owp/6/ And I have to keep "SWIZ" option in select box for some reason.
I need the "0" value to be set for all the scope items when i select "SWIZ" option from select drop-down.

```
$scope.months =
    [{ "country": "UK", "mon": "JAN", "A": "14", "S": "2"},
     { "country": "AUSTRIA", "mon": "JAN", "A": "24", "S": "12"},
     { "country": "ITALY", "mon": "JAN",  "A": "5", "S": "21"},

     { "country": "UK", "mon": "FEB", "A": "4", "S": "12"},
     { "country": "AUSTRIA", "mon": "FEB", "A": "24", "S": "12"},
     { "country": "ITALY", "mon": "FEB",  "A": "15", "S": "1"}

    ];
    $scope.countries = ["UK", "AUSTRIA", "ITALY", "SWIZ"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forked your fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/g81a10ze/1/

```
if(fData.length > 0){
    this.filteredData = fData;
} else {
this.filteredData = [{ "country": "SWIZ", "mon": "JAN", "A": "0", "S": "0"},                                                          
                     { "country": "SWIZ", "mon": "FEB", "A": "0", "S": "0"}]
}
```

Comment: Can it be more configurable? I mean if there would be a case when select box  include more than one options similar to "SWIZ" and data not available accordingly..

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
if(fData.length > 0){
                                    this.filteredData = fData;
                                } else {
                                    this.filteredData = [{},{}];
                                }`
```

and in html

```
 <tr>
     <td>{{selectedCountry=='SWIZ'?0:month.A}}</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>{{selectedCountry=='SWIZ'?0:month.S}}</td>                                           
 </tr>
```

Comment: Can it be more configurable? I mean if there would be a case when select box include more than one options similar to "SWIZ" and data not available accordingly..